# How to block an AJAX request from creating a new session

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session, cookies

I have developed an application in ASP.NET MVC that does not uses cookies.I store some values in session variables once a user is authenticated .However, these values are cleared when I make an AJAX request. On googling I found out that an AJAX request creates a new session. Is there a way to block AJAX from creating a new session and using the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has provided ENUM values in System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior that allow us to give up rights to an exclusive session lock. Mainly the values:

- ReadOnly – Doesn’t block other requests because this request can’t
  update session
- Disabled – Can’t block, and your best option for    performance in
  StateServer & SQL modes because no serialization needs    to occur.
  Remember that all of session is serialized and    de-serialized per
  user every time. Not just particular keys your are    accessing.

  [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]

  public class TestController : Controller
          {

  ```
          public ActionResult Index()
          {
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
              return new EmptyResult();
          }
      }
  ```